# Angular2 Deal with Observable<Array<Object>>

Tags: arrays, angular

I do receive from a service an `Observable<Array<Object>>`

I would like to apply a function to each element of the Array and return the result in an Observable. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
getFoo() {
   let f: Observable<Array<Object>> = serviceCall()
   return f.map(res => res.forEach(v => myFunction(v)))
}
```

Any idea how I could do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return a new array, it just executes the code for each item. Use `map()` instead:

```
getFoo() {
   let f: Observable<Array<Object>> = serviceCall()
   return f.map(res => res.map(v => myFunction(v)))
}
```